# Numerically stable evaluation of sqrt(x+a) - sqrt(x)

Tags: math, floating-point, numeric

Is there an elegant way of numerically stable evaluating the following expression for the full parameter range x,a >= 0?

```
f(x,a) = sqrt(x+a) - sqrt(x)
```

Also is there *any* programming language or library that does provide this kind of function? If yes, under what name? I have no specific problem using the above expression right now, but encountered it many times in the past and always thought that this problem must have been solved before!

Comment: Some libraries, notably Boost, offer a function `sqrt1pm1()` designed to compute sqrt(x+1)-1 accurately. If you already use such a library you could use that function to implement `sqrt(x+a)-sqrt(x)` as `sqrt1pm1 (a/x) * sqrt (x)` in a numerically robust fashion.

Comment: @njuffa: Ah, very interesting. While functions like `log1p` and `expm1` are commonplace, I've never encountered `sqrt1pm1` before.  On one hand, it seems odd to create a separate function for that when it's so easy to emulate.  On the other hand, I'd definitely have found occasion to use it if it were available in the C standard library.

Comment: @MarkDickinson As Kahan has shown, `log1p` and `expm1` are also easy to emulate. Presumably the point of providing such functions  in a library is to provide the fastest and most accurate implementations to programmers who are not particularly knowledgeable about numerical analysis.

Comment: @njuffa: I'd say that that's a rather different value of "easy". :-)  See for example the [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Modules/_math.c#L215-L255) for the considerations involved in trying to emulate `log1p` in situations where neither the floating-point format nor the current rounding mode can be depended on.

Comment: @njuffa: interesting to know about the sqrtpm1 function. This is actually what I wanted to learn... The disadvantage of the approach is of course that one has to add the special case of x=0...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is!  Provided that at least one of `x` and `a` is positive, you can use:

```
f(x, a) = a / (sqrt(x + a) + sqrt(x))
```

which is perfectly numerically stable, but hardly worth a library function in its own right.  Of course, when `x = a = 0`, the result should be `0`.

Explanation: `sqrt(x + a) - sqrt(x)` is equal to `(sqrt(x + a) - sqrt(x)) * (sqrt(x + a) + sqrt(x)) / (sqrt(x + a) + sqrt(x))`.  Now multiply the first two terms to get `sqrt(x+a)^2 - sqrt(x)^2`, which simplifies to `a`.

Here's an example demonstrating the stability: the troublesome case for the original expression is where `x + a` and `x` are very close in value (or equivalently when `a` is much smaller in magnitude than `x`).  For example, if `x = 1` and `a` is small, we know from a Taylor expansion around `1` that `sqrt(1 + a)` should be `1 + a/2 - a^2/8 + O(a^3)`, so `sqrt(1 + a) - sqrt(1)` should be close to `a/2 - a^2/8`.  Let's try that for a particular choice of small `a`. Here's the original function (written in Python, in this case, but you can treat it as pseudocode):

```
def f(x, a):
    return sqrt(x + a) - sqrt(x)
```

and here's the stable version:

```
def g(x, a):
    if a == 0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return a / ((sqrt(x + a) + sqrt(x))
```

Now let's see what we get with `x = 1` and `a = 2e-10`:

```
>>> a = 2e-10
>>> f(1, a)
1.000000082740371e-10
>>> g(1, a)
9.999999999500001e-11
```

The value we should have got is (up to machine accuracy): `a/2 - a^2/8` - for this particular `a`, the cubic and higher order terms are insignificant in the context of IEEE 754 double-precision floats, which only provide around 16 decimal digits of precision.  Let's compute that value for comparison:

```
>>> a/2 - a**2/8
9.999999999500001e-11
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Although it does not work for x=a=0 it is much better than the original.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Yes, for a library-quality function, you'd want to special-case `x = a = 0`.

Comment: I've edited in a special case for `a = 0`.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Thanks. Do you know by chance a resource where numerically stable evaluation of certain functions is listed? Like a handbook or so? I find it particularly hard to search for specific formulas in the internet...

Comment: I don't, I'm afraid.  I've picked up tips and tricks from all sorts of different sources, but I don't know of a single resource for this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @AndreasH. Two basic guiding principles are: (1) Avoid subtractive cancellation,  i.e. the effective subtraction of two quantities of almost equal magnitude (2) For nested operations, use contracting operations for the outer layers, e.g sqrt(1/x) will return more accurate results than 1/sqrt(x).

Comment: @njuffa: Why is sqrt(1/x) more accurate than 1/sqrt(x) ? This is not clear to me. It should not make any difference, should it?!

Comment: @AndreasH: The square root operation has the effect of *decreasing* (roughly, halving) relative error from previous computations, so an outer sqrt call tends to contribute positively to numerical stability.

Comment: @AndreasH. You might find the following book a useful resource: Nicholas J. Higham, Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, 2nd ed, SIAM 2002

Comment: I'm not sure about special-casing `x=a=0`.  Is your formula well-behaved *near* `x=a=0` ?

Comment: @DonHatch I _think_ so, yes. Even if `x` and/or `a` is a subnormal, and continuing to assume that both `x` and `a` are nonnegative, the square roots are well within the normal range, so I can't see any place that you'd be losing more than a handful of ulps of accuracy. (With a bit of time and a sufficiently large piece of paper, it should be possible to come up with an actual upper bound on the error in ulps.) Hmm, though now I notice that I'm not insisting that both `x` and `a` are nonnegative. Needs some thought.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Stack Overflow needs a "thank you" button. I used this today.